# "Startup Applications" not working

Tags: command-line, startup-applications

I have a simple one line command which works perfectly in terminal, but does not work in the "Startup Applications" app thing.

The line of code is : `xmodmap /home/seph/Code/Ubuntu\ Scripts/Xmodmap`

It's not that much of a hassle to copy it from "Startup Applications" and paste it into terminal, but I don't really get why it isn't working.  I followed someone else's instructions to do it in the first place, so maybe I did something wrong?  In any case, wouldn't it be the obvious and logical assumption that it just types whatever you put in it into Terminal?

Comment: That's exact same problem that I had! +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Commands, especially those related to keyboard, mouse, and touchpad settings, or `xrandr` commands, often need the desktop to be fully loaded. If you run them simply at login (using Startup Applications), they often run too soon and break.

Therefore, you need to introduce a little time break before your actual command runs. Use the following command instead to add to Startup Applications:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xmodmap /home/seph/Code/Ubuntu\ Scripts/Xmodmap"
```

Open the dash → Startup Applications → *Add*, and add the command.

That should do the trick.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wonder why the delay is needed though. X should be fully up and running by the login. I mean I know there's this issue, it's not the first time read about it, I just wonder why is that.

Comment: @kos I suspect at a certain point, the local settings are applied, overruling the command on startup (since they pop up later).

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try to research this a bit, I'm mildly curious about that.

Comment: @kos ...In other cases, it *is* the desktop, being not ready yet. I remember a bug in Dropbox, where the icon appeared on the left side (Unity) of the panel, could be fixed with the same trick.

Comment: this explains a lot.  Almost every startup script I've really needed has had something to do with fixing the keyboard or mouse.  I find it strange that this is not a use case which was planned around.

Comment: in ~/.conf/autostart are a bunch of "*.desktop" files. Inside each one is something like X-MATE-Autostart-Delay=10 or whatever. I do not know if / whether / how these things might relate to / conflict with / overlap / override the "Startup Applications" GUI, but I did stumble across them and thought I'd mention them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet into a `.conf` file in `~/.config/upstart/`:

```
start on startup
task
exec xmodmap /home/seph/Code/Ubuntu\ Scripts/Xmodmap
```

Comment: add it where?  upstart is a folder.   Should I make a new file?  What kind of extension should it have?

Comment: into a conf file in the folder. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried this with `exec xrandr --output DP-1 --brightness 0.85` but it had no effect. could it be that `on startup` is too soon? what event signifies that the unity desktop is ready?

Comment: @Superole for me xrandr works when executed in ~/.profile