# run a script when a session starts

Tags: unity, scripts, startup, session

I'm using ubuntu 15.10(unity), I want some scripts running when a session starts. I tried the following methods:

1. Put those scripts in the file `~/.xsession`, but it didn't work (It worked when I executed those scripts manually in gnome-terminal).
2. Add those scripts to `Startup Applications` in unity, it didn't work, either. I guess it's because `Startup Applications` runs those scripts when OS starts, but the scripts that I want to run demands a session.

How to achieve this?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/a/708043/72216 not sure what the script should do, but if it runs from a terminal once logged in, this is pretty much certainly the cause.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you, that actually solved my problem ^^