# How can I make a script autostart after I log into my computer on Ubuntu Mate 15.10?

Tags: scripts, 15.10, mate, autostart

I'd like to automatically disable the touchpad on my Thinkpad X301 after the system boots up.

I can successfully run the script manually, but when I try to execute it by any autostart method, it just won't do.

The script looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0
exit 0
```

- I checked that the ID is correct with `xinput list`.
- I have granted execution rights to the script.

What I've tried with no success:

- to add it to Startup Applications in Control Center
- put a `disable_touchpad.desktop` file to `~/.config/autostart` with the following content:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=/home/username/disable_touchpad.sh
  Hidden=false
  NoDisplay=false
  X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
  Name=Disable Touchpad
  Icon=/home/username/Pictures/icon_touchpad.png
  ```

I also tried to put the script from my home folder to `/usr/local/bin` (and edit the file above accordingly), did not make any difference.

Currently I put the script to my Desktop and I manually execute it every time.

I know that there is one more way to try, which is using `crontab` and `@reboot`, but I would prefer the options above and would really like to know why these approaches don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if the script executes at all? Maybe add a `date > /tmp/log` to it and see if the file `/tmp/log` gets created?

Comment: Well, if I execute it manually it disables the touchpad with no problem.
Do you think I should add it to the script anyway?

Comment: There are two possibilities: either the script executes at startup and something else fails, or the script doesn't execute at startup. We can eliminate one possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, editinit's recommendation worked. So the script ran successfully. But thank you again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Startup Applications" not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/708012/startup-applications-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be ubuntu-mate startup program taking time to load(touchpad driver). you can try adding sleep into your above script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0
exit 0
```

Please increase the sleep time if above does not work.

Comment: You're a genius! :)
It did not work with 30, but I increased it to 60 and it's perfect.
I added the script to startup applications and now it works like a charm.
Thank you!