# Make keyboard right alt ctrl work as mouse left right click buttons

Tags: xkb, remapping

I am using ubuntu 19.04. in windows i have used autohotkey to make keyboard right alt and ctrl behave as mouse left and right click. 
But i am unable to do this in ubuntu.
I have tried editting /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc with text editor.
I have sucessfuly made ctrl behave like menu key, but unable to make behave like mouse button.
I am doing this because my laptop mouse buttons are not working.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you need to install the terminal tools `xdotool` and `xcape`.

1) First create "normal" hotkeys that emulate the mouse buttons. You can do this in "Settings" - "Devices" - "Keyboard shortcuts". You can use crazy key combinations you otherwise will never use.

At the bottom of the pane, press the "+" button. Provide a name, provide the following command:

```
xdotool keyup ctrl+alt+shift+z click 1
```

and assign the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. The `keyup` part simulates a release of the hotkey that triggers the command, so make sure it matches the hotkey you use.

Continue in a similar way for the right click. This time, the command is

```
xdotool keyup ctrl+alt+shift+x click 3
```

which is assigned to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

2) Now use `xcape` to redirect pressing and releasing modifier keys on their own to one of these commands.

```
xcape -e 'ISO_Level3_Shift=Shift_L|Control_L|Alt_L|z;Control_R=Shift_L|Control_L|Alt_L|x'"
```

What follows after the option `-e` is the remapping. In this example, the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is remapped to the hotkey we set up for the left click. After the semi colon `;` the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is being remapped to the one for the right click.

Find out the names of your modifier keys using `xev | grep keysym` (installed by default). Start this tool in the terminal. When you press or release a key, a line is generated containing the name of the key.

3) If it works well, you will want to have the command [automatically executed during login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730397/how-can-i-make-a-script-autostart-after-i-log-into-my-computer-on-ubuntu-mate-15). In your `.desktop` file, insert the command `sh -c "sleep 0.3 ; xcape -e 'ISO_Level3_Shift=Shift_L|Control_L|Alt_L|z;Control_R=Shift_L|Control_L|Alt_L|x'"` on the `Exec=` line.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using both xbindkeys and xmacro

this is basically the same setup as AHK for linux.

**create these three files**

*~/rightclick.macro*

`ButtonPress 2
Delay 100
ButtonRelease 2`

*~/leftclick.macro*

`ButtonPress 1
Delay 100
ButtonRelease 1`

*~/.xbindkeysrc*

`#right control mouse click
"cat ~/rightclick.macro|xmacroplay :0"
Control_R`

`#right alt mouse click
"cat ~/leftclick.macro |xmacroplay :0"
Alt_R`

now run `xbindkeys`

if you want this to start as soon as you log in everytime add the `xbindkeys` command to *~/.xinitrc*

you may need to install both xbindkeys and xmacro packages if you haven't already :)

Comment: Another way to skin a cat. Thank you for sharing. Your approach looks more simple than mine.

Comment: thank you, your solution is interesting i havent used xcape before

Comment: `xcape` allows to have the action triggered only after releasing the key, so the modifier key can still be used normally in combination with other keys. I guess you can also do that with xbindkeys, appending ` + release` after the key.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing the problem, there is a tool called [Keymapper](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/remap-keyboard-and-mouse-buttons-on.html). it is a gui tool to easily remap anything from keyboards to joysticks and even touchpad buttons.