# How to make portrait mode display permanent on 15.10

Tags: 15.10, xrandr, display-rotation

I tried several methods from several forums but nothing worked for me. I want my display to come in portrait mode after boot.

After login if I manually rotate screen from terminal by command `xrandr -o left` it will rotating fine. But I am wondering in which file should I add this command so that my screen becomes portrait for permanent.

Comment: 15.10 is no longer supported. Upgrade to 16.04 or 16.10.

Answer (score 1):

Add following to startup application :

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&xrandr -o left"
```

The reason adding 15 second of break to prevent `xrandr` command performed too early, which cause desktop to break while the desktop is still loading. [@Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/a/708043/253251) explain why this is necessary.

[image]

#### Apply change to LightDM

Open your favourite text editor, I'll use gedit for example. With root privileges, because we're gonna modify system directory.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add following entries to opened gedit.

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=xrandr -o left
```

Save the file then.

**WARNING:** Haven't tested, because it's not something I want to (have to un-)do on my machine. If the X failed to start, use [recovery mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/) to remove the file.

Comment: it works but the screen rotates only after login. Is there a way to make login screen also portrait.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar Edited

Comment: Thanks for your support. Both of your suggestions are working but still I am facing an undesired behavior. This lightdm.conf change makes the login screen portrait mode. But when I press enter on login the screen changes back to landscape. Now After 15 seconds of login the screen again changes to portrait mode(because of start up application change). Is it possible to avoid the transition from portrait to landscape on login?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar I believe you need a little tweak on `sleep 15` to see what is needed.